# How to find out whats slowing down my asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net

I have written around 5k lines in 3 days for my new website. There are a lot places where leaks or Querys for the database can be the reason for slowing my page down but the fact is a single website-call needs around 2 full seconds whats very long i think.

1) How can I meassure the exact time what my page needs to load? (To Compare after I disable a query or change a query if it wirks)

2) How to find the leak / the thing that is slowing down my asp.net site the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in page load..

```
Trace.IsEnabled = true;
```

It will show everything with time taken by every page events namely life cycle..

You can keep track of time lagging here and then proceed accordingly..

Comment: Nice thing, didnt know that, gives me a lot of information, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) on the applications I work on. If you have SQL Server as data store then use SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are being executed. Other than that, it's mostly grunt work when it comes to tracking performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a profile to check out the execution time each of your methods in a page is taking, for this many tools both free and paid ones are available. You can check out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) which is a nice free tool, available on nuget and is preferred by most.